# Onclick command wont send ID to text box, onclick needs "escaping" to be recognized as code

Tags: javascript, vbscript, onclick

Hi there I hope I made sense, I'm working on an assignment, but I can.t remember how to sort of escape a line of code, so the code I need is seen as code? If that makes sense.

I have this section:

```
<input type="text" name="firstSeat" id="firstSeat" readonly="readonly" style="border: solid; background-color: #374B5C; color: #fff; width:30px;"/>
```

So that box has the ID firstSeat, and I want to populate it with an ID like A01, using this code;

**EDIT** I'm having trouble pasting my code in here, some of it doesn't show up, so I hope these are OK.

Code is here too **https://gist.github.com/7f54751e1563e778d482**

So you can see on line 10 and 13, there is this code:

```
<%Do While Not thrus.EOF
 dim seatID
 seatID=thrus("sea_ID")
 bookedcheck="SELECT * FROM booking WHERE boo_PerID = " & request("per_ID") &" AND booking.boo_seaID = "& seatID&""
 booked.Open bookedcheck, conx, adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic
 if (thrus("sea_Reference") = "B01") OR  (thrus("sea_Reference") = "C01") OR  (thrus("sea_Reference") = "D01") OR  (thrus("sea_Reference") = "E01")OR  (thrus("sea_Reference") = "F01")OR  (thrus("sea_Reference") = "G01")Then
    Response.write "<br />"
 end if
 if not booked.EOF then
    response.write("<href='#"&thrus("sea_Reference")&"'><img src='images/booked.gif' border='0' title='"&thrus("sea_Reference")&", SEAT BOOKED' onclick='document.getElementById('firstSeat').value='"&thrus("sea_Reference")&"';' /></>")
 else
    response.write("<a href='#"&thrus("sea_Reference")&"'><img src='images/"&thrus("sea_ICON")&"' border='0' title='"&thrus("sea_Reference")&", &pound;120,  45 degree left seating icon facing stage' onclick='document.getElementById('firstSeat').value='"&thrus("sea_Reference")&"';' /></a>")

end if%>
```

So whats supposed to happen is onclick it pushes sea_reference, to firstSeat and passes it to that box up there. But when I click it it doesn't send it.

I believe its because of this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGpkP.png

The onclick is seen as the same information as most of the code on that line.

I think I need to "escape" so that the onclick command is seen.

If anyone can help, or indeed help me to get my code in here! that would be great, 
thanks.

**Update** If it helps to see the page; http://heweb.grimsby.ac.uk/STUDENT/s0191958/PART2/booking.asp?the_ID=1&per_ID=1

Comment: Can you provide a JsFiddle? https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/6928617728/hA937289F/

Comment: @DumbProducts Ive never fiddled before, do you just want the code on this website instead?

Comment: It's easy. Just use jsfiddle.net

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't bind the event handler in javascript? It's cleaner and you wouldn't need to worry about any escaping.

Comment: @DumbProducts Sorry pasting all my code in there didnt really do anything- im not great at this. lol

Comment: @jbabey Hi im new to this, so im not sure what you mean, thanks

Comment: @Kieronboz I believe he's talking about jQuery. Look it up.

Comment: @Kieronboz yeah well post each bit of your code in different categories, IE javascript, jquery, html, css ect.

Comment: @DumbProducts I really only have the onclick as JS in the page, the rest is just ASP and SQL. full code here; http://pastie.org/private/9yk49jerkfjitfgxs52yq

Comment: @Kieronboz Oh it's vbscript! You should add that to the tags.... VBSCRIPT can't be executed on any fiddle...

Comment: @DumbProducts Ah right, so I am, lol. Thanks :P Tag Added

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your code is using the wrong quotations causing breaks, using single quotes denotes a string literal; in your code when using those single quotes you are effectively closing the literal and starting another after `firstSeat` by putting them in there to pass your parameter. Use double-quotes.

This is a half-assed answer but maybe this will help.

Replace what you have with this and see if that gets you somewhere.

`onclick='document.getElementById("firstSeat").value=thrus("sea_Reference")'`

Comment: Hi, I have tried to add your fix into my code, but I am so messed up in quotes and double quotes im not sure what is neccessary anymore at the end "onclick='document.getElementById('firstSeat').value='"&thrus("sea_Reference")&"';' /></>")"

Comment: I was mobile, I'm sorry I don't think I fully grasped what you were asking. Disregard my solution.

Answer (score 0):

To change your element id,all you have to do is this:

```
onclick=document.getElementById('firstSeat').id="sea_Reference"
```

also to change the element value use:

```
onclick=document.getElementById('sea_Reference').value="value"
```

as the id attribute has changed before you should use the new id to reference.

if you have a function that returns data as id or value as a string,you don't have to wrap it with double or single quotes.just hold the value in a variable and do the formatting you like on the variable, then assign it to the property(in JS).or if you are at the server-side, concatenate the variable to the string you want to print.(in a server-side language)

Comment: Hi, sorry, if i was better at this im sure i would be able to understand what youve done here- im new :P

Perhaps seeing the page will allow me to explain better; http://heweb.grimsby.ac.uk/STUDENT/s0191958/PART2/booking.asp?the_ID=1&per_ID=1

but sea_reference is different for every onclick, so i cant see why i would put it in the getelementbyid, thanks!